# WPF Cross-Thread MessageBox not blocking main thread input

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm trying to show a `MessageBox` from another `Thread` using [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjBvNKe273KAhXG56YKHcUyC7oQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fzh-tw%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v%3Dvs.110%29.aspx&usg=AFQjCNFTDnBk1AaINtq3qshX13cjDD2_Sw&cad=rja).

The `MessageBox` did show up. But without clicking the `OK` button on the `MessageBox`, I can still control the main window.

I'm thinking if there's a way to block the main window input before clicking the `OK` button?

Any help is appreciated.

Code I have so far:

```
void ShowError(String message)  //I call this function in another thread
{
    if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        MessageBox.Show(message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    else
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            new Action(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to the window from the code calling ShowError or in the class containing ShowError?

Comment: Yes, let me try your solution. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to be guaranteed that the message box blocks the window is by passing the window in to the message box.

```
void ShowError(String message, Window windowToBlock)  //I call this function in another thread
{
    if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        MessageBox.Show(windowToBlock, message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    else
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            new Action(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(windowToBlock, message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I didn't know the [MessageBox.Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598703%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method has a `owner` parameter.